# Looking for formula of $\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k \dfrac {x^2(x^2-1)...(x^2-k+1)}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let

\begin{equation*}
u_k:=(-1)^k \dfrac {x^2(x^2-1)...(x^2-k+1)}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+k)}.
\end{equation*}

Can we find the sum of first $m$ of $u_k$ 's? That is, is there any formula for $\sum _{k=1}^m u_k$ ?

Comment: It's worth noting that $u_k={\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k} \left( {x}^{2} \right) !\,x!}{ \left( 
{x}^{2}-k \right) !\, \left( x+k \right) !}}
$

Comment: Hint. Your sum is a telescoping one.

Comment: @OlivierOloa : I don't know whether it is actually   telescoping  in its original form or not but I have been able to establish $(x+k+1)u_{k+1}-(x+k)u_k=-(x^2+x)u_k$ , it is telescoping then the left hand side and so $-(x^2+x)\sum _{k=1}^n u_k=(x+n+1)u_{n+1}-(x+1)u_1$

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account  Pauly B's and Olivier Oloa's comments, you could establish that, if $$u_k={\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k} \left( {x}^{2} \right) !\,x!}{ \left(  {x}^{2}-k \right) !\, \left( x+k \right) !}}$$ then $$\sum_{k=1}^m u_k=\frac{(-1)^m  x! \left(x^2-2\right)!}{(x+m)!
   \left(x^2-m-1\right)!}(x-1) x+\frac{1}{x+1}-1$$ Tedious (at least to me) but doable !